# How to dynamically generate a ContextMenu in WAF

Tags: c#, waf-framework-c#

How to procedurally (dynamically) create a context menu in waf-framework-c# C#?

More description: I have been trying to use this code:

```
System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu m = new System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu();
m.Items.Add("Cut");
m.Items.Add("Copy");
m.Items.Add("Paste");          
m.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
m.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

However nothing is showing up. The program doesn't crash either. Then I tried this:

```
grid.Children.Add(m);
```

And I got this error:

> 'ContextMenu' cannot have a logical or visual parent.

Comment: Please [edit] the title of your question to something that describes the problem you're having. It's irrelevant to everyone that you're new to C# and you were wondering about something. Your title should describe the specific problem you're experiencing in a way that will be useful to others in the future finding it in a search result. If I was looking next month for information about creating a context menu in that framework, would it be relevant to me to find "Hey I'm new to C sharp and I was wondering" as a result of that search? I think not.

Comment: To expand on @KenWhite's comment, you are seriously reducing your chances of getting an answer when you have a question title that starts with  "Hey I'm new to C sharp and I was wondering". Many of the professional programmers who hang out here at SO consider a title like that to be a good indication that there isn't anything in the question that will be interesting or challenging, and will simply avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
grid.ContextMenu = m;
```

But you must have some childrens in your grid and only on that control's context menu will appear by right click.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow (SO)!

I think all you probably have to do is attach the context menu to the treeview. Look at the available properties of the treeview and see if you can assign (at design or run time), the context menu as a property of the treeview. Otherwise, the treeview is oblivious to the existence of the context menu.

I know in WinForms, a treeview has a ContextMenu property.